# Custom OverlayView causing issues upon high zoom

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make my own version of the richMarker google maps overlay. (https://github.com/googlemaps/js-rich-marker).

I have a working overlay that appears and behaves correctly on the map except when the map is zoomed to a level >= 19. When the map is zoomed to that level my overlay disappears and also the google maps controls start to flicker in and out when the the map is panned. Zooming back out to a level < 19 brings back normal map behavior.

Now i've seen this issue ([Google Maps overlay disappears at certain zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393892/google-maps-overlay-disappears-at-certain-zoom-level)) that states all i have to do is add this line and everything will work.

`div.style.webkitTransform = 'translateZ(0px)';`

But that isn't working for me. (its present in the jsFiddle below)

I've narrowed down the issue to have something to do with VERY large `top` and `left` values for the placement of the overlay as generated by the `draw` method.

[image: Marker issue]

If i manually force these values to be smaller or force the marker to be hidden via display=none or visibility=collapse then the map behaves correctly.

Here is the code that generates these values:

```
    var latLng = this.get('position');
    var pos = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(latLng);

    var offset = this.getOffset_();
    this.markerWrapper_.style['top'] = (pos.y + offset.height) + 'px';
    this.markerWrapper_.style['left'] = (pos.x + offset.width) + 'px';
```

As far as i can tell this is the recomended way of putting an overlay on a map as this exact block is used in multiple examples on the google maps API reference page. (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-hideshow)

I've tried creating an overlay that checks the map bounds and then hides the markers that are out of bounds but the `draw()` method is not called when the user pans the map.

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Here is a JSFiddle that shows the problem. Just play around with the map at a very low zoom level and you'll see it start to go wonky. 
https://jsfiddle.net/ten5d3y8/2/

FYI i have seen this on Chrome and Safari but haven't had a chance to test it in other browsers.

Comment: I was seeing what you mean. Probably a bug in the API.  Seemed to work in the ["frozen" version (v=3.0)](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ten5d3y8/5/).  But now it seems to be working everywhere.

Comment: I'm still seeing it in the fiddle you just posted.

Comment: What browser(s)?  It is working for me in Chrome.  (and in the [experimental version](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ten5d3y8/6/)

Comment: Chrome( 45.0.2454.101 m).  I just cleared cache too..

Comment: 45.0.2454.99 m on one machine (don't see the issue), 45.0.2454.101 m on another, see the issue.  Seems like it might be a Chrome bug...

Comment: You could try filing a bug for it on the tracker.